# Writing simple chat by using push notification in c#

Tags: c#, rest

I was testing Push Notification and wanted to do some simple exercise by creating simple chat with use on .net rest API. In controller first thing first I create concurrent bag for subscribed clients.

```
private static readonly ConcurrentBag<StreamWriter> Clients; 
static ChatController()  
{  
    Clients = new ConcurrentBag<StreamWriter>();  
}
```

Next I need method to aggregate Subscribers to that list I created this like:

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("Subscribe")]  
public HttpResponseMessage  Subscribe()  
{  
    void OnStreamAvailable(Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)  
    {  
        var client = new StreamWriter(stream);  
        Clients.Add(client);  
    }

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        Content = new PushStreamContent(OnStreamAvailable, "text/event-stream"),
    };
    
    return response;
}
```

So logic here is easy each time someone subscribes push stream content add that client to subscription list.

Also Post message method:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Post")]  
public async Task Post(Message message)  
{
    async Task ChatCallbackMsg(Message callbackMessage)
    {
        foreach (var client in Clients)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = $"data:{callbackMessage.Username}|{callbackMessage.Text}|{callbackMessage.Timestamp}\n\n";
                await client.WriteAsync(data);
                await client.FlushAsync();
                await client.DisposeAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Clients.TryTake(out _);
            }
        }
    }

    await ChatCallbackMsg(message);  
}
```

Also easy, for each subscribed client I push message as notification.

im testing this by simply hooking to EventSource object in browser js console by

```
let sse = new EventSource('http://localhost:5284/api/Chat/Subscribe')
```

and then use post method in swagger.

Now the problem is that PushStreamContent does execute its action OnStreamAvaiable parameter when someone is connecting, and can not find any clue why?

Or maybe that is a wrong approach?